# Длина border-bottom меняется в зависимости от количества слов в строке

Tags: html, css, border

Как сделать чтобы длина border-bottom изменялась в зависимости от количества слов.Т.е больше слов-меньше длина,меньше слов-больше соответственно.Как на рисунке,чтоб длина изменялась в зависимости от количества слов,по разному в каждой строке.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хорошо бы разметку свою показывать... Такой вариант:

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin: 10px;
}

li span {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #999;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Рабочий объем<span></span>3990.0</li>
  <li>Цвет<span></span>Красный</li>
  <li>Номер кузова<span></span>100500</li>
  <li>Год выпуска<span></span>1889</li>
  <li>Номер двигателя<span></span>087915</li>
  <li>Номер двигателя<span></span>05</li>
  <li>VIN<span></span>1HGCR2F35GA8TY54</li>
</ul>
```